# Edit NVD3 lineChart grid

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, linechart

I'm working on project and I'm using NVD3 lineChart, and I couldn't edit chart's grid.

This is the chart's options:

```
chart: {
        type: 'lineChart',
        height: 430,
        margin: {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 80,
            left: 40
        },
        x: function (d) {
            return d.x;
        },
        y: function (d) {
            return d.y;
        },
        useInteractiveGuideline: true,
        xAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'Date',
            showMaxMin: false,
            tickFormat: function (d) {
                return d3.time.format('%b %d')(new Date(d));
            },
            reduceXTicks: false,
            ticks: 13
        },
        yAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'People count',
            tickFormat: function (d) {
                return d3.format('1d')(d);
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        enable: true,
        text: 'People count Vs Date'
    }
```

I want to have 7 grid x-axis if there're 7 values for example.

Notice: By editing ticks value to any number the grid doesn't change.

And this is the current chart

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yfin991k0ovycnv/chart.png?dl=0

So, how can I edit chart grid?

Answer (score 0):

The lineChart model exposes the axis as xAxis and yAxis, and those have options on them as well.  For instance, you can do:

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart();
chart.xAxis.ticks(1);
chart.yAxis.tickVAlues([1,2,3,4,5]);
```

Most of those options are based on D3 options, for the above example see:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#ticks  (tickValues is right below that one)

For a full list of axis options in nvd3, see the documentation from the community fork here:

https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#axis